# USB hardddisk disconnected while copying a big file

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, file-transfer, temporary-files, interrupts

I was copying a big file (20GB) in my USB external harddisk. But because of a problem in my USB port, the connection suddenly cut off. And copying process is naturally interrupted. Now I compare the capacity of the harddisk and the files inside it, and there is a 20GB difference, although the file is not there.

How can I clear this invisible temporary file(s) in my harddisk, without formatting it?

Comment: Filesystem? OS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer. My External Hard-Disk has a Recycle Bin in its root folder. And the suspicious file was moved there somehow. I couldn't find a way to view it. But I used these codes to locate it:

```
cd E
dir /s /a
cd $Recycle.bin
```

And then I removed the file, and problem solved.

Answer (score 1):

An aborted copy process don’t usually leave a temporary file behind and even less a hidden one. Nevertheless you can run

```
cd E:\
dir /AH /S
```

From the DOS prompt where `E:` is the USB drive assigned letter.